# Even with flexbox and explicit maximum height, div grows beyond these limits

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I'm having some behavior with HTML and CSS that I don't understand and I'm hoping that someone could elucidate it: https://jsfiddle.net/kufd2x96/1/:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <style>
          #fixedDiv{
            position: fixed;
            top: 32px;
            left: 0px;
            height: calc(100vw - 32px);
            background-color: blue;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
          }
          #bigSomething{
            overflow-y: auto;
            background-color: green;
            flex-grow: 1;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
        <div id="fixedDiv">
          <div>
            Small Something
          </div>
          <div id="bigSomething">
            Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>v
              Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>v
                Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>Something<br>v
          </div>
        </div>  
      </body>
    </html>
```

**What I expect to happen and why:**

In this MCVE, since #fixedDiv is set to have a height that brings it exactly to the bottom of the page, since flexbox (I thought, I saw a few SO answers that claimed as much) guarantees that the internal elements won't grow any larger than their container, and since #bigSometing has `overflow-y: auto;` I expect everything to stay on screen and for #bigContent to get a scrollbar so everything is accessible.

**What actually happens:**

Instead, #bigContent grows to well beyond the bottom of the screen, but to a seemingly random height since it doesn't grow far enough to contain its entire contents (as can be inferred from the fact that a functional scrollbar is present).

**The Question:**

Why is this code not behaving how I expect it to, where #bigContent's area is entirely on the screen and where it gets a scrollbar, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue: I had vw when I should have had vh, so the calculation was based on the width of the page, as if the width were the height.